# Postgres 9.0 and pgpool replication : single point of failure?

Tags: postgresql, failover, pgpool

My application uses Postgresql 9.0 and is composed by one or more stations that interacts with a global database: it is like a common client server application but to avoid any additional hardware, all stations include both client and server: a main station is promoted to act also as server, and any other act as a client to it. This solution permits me to be scalable: a user may initially need a single station but it can decide to expand to more in future without a useless separate server in the initial phase.

I'm trying to avoid that if main station goes down all others stop working; to do it the best solution could be to continuously replicate the main database to unused database on one or more stations.

Searching I've found that pgpool can be used for my needs but from all examples and tutorial it seems that **point of failure moves from main database to server that runs pgpool**.

I read something about multiple pgpool and heartbeat tool but it isn't clear how to do it.

Considering my architecture, where doesn't exist separated and specialized servers, can someone give me some hints ? In case of failover it seems that pgpool do everything in automatic, can I consider that failover situation can be handled by a standard user without the intervention of an administrator ?

Comment: Attaching bounty here. I'm also interested in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

For these kind of applications I really like [Amazon's Dynamo](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html) design. The document by the link is quite big, but it is worth reading. In fact, there're applications that already implement this approach:

- [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [Project Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/)

Maybe others, but I'm not aware. Cassandra started within Facebook, Voldemort is the one used by LinkedIn. Making things distributed and adding redundancy into your data distribution you will step away from traditional Master-Slave replication approaches.

If you'd like to stay with PostgreSQL, it shouldn't be a big deal to implement such approach. You will need to implement an extra layer (a proxy), that will decide based on pre-configured options how to retrieve/save the data.

The proxying layer can be implemented in:

- application (requires lot's of work IMHO);
- database;
- as a middleware.

You can use [PL/Proxy](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL/Proxy) on the middleware layer, project originated in Skype. It is deeply integrated into the PostgreSQL, so I'd say it is a combination of options 2 and 3. PL/Proxy will require you to use functions for all kind of queries against the database.
In case you will hit performance issues, [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) can be used.

Last note: any way you decide to go, a known amount of development will be required.

**EDIT:**

It all depends on what you call “failure” and what you consider system being in an interrupted state.

Let's look on the [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) features.

1. **Connection Pooling** PostgreSQL is using a single process (fork) per session. Obviously, if you have a very busy site, you'll hit the OS limit. To overcome this, connection poolers are used. They also allow you to use your resources evenly, so generally it's a good idea to have pooler *before* your database.
   In case of pgpool outage you'll face a big number of clients unable to reach your database. If you'll point them directly to the database, avoiding pooler, you'll face performance issues.
2. **Replication** All your queries will be auto-replicated to slave instances. This has meaning for the DML and DDL queries.
   In case of pgpool outage your replication will stop and slaves will not be able to catchup with master, as there's no change tracking done outside pgpool (as far as I know).
3. **Load Balance** Your read-only queries will be spread across several instances, achieving nice response times, allowing you to put more bandwidth on the system.
   In case of pgpool outage your queries will suddenly run much slower, if the system is capable of handling such a load. And this is in the case that master database will catchup instead of failed pgpool.
4. **Limiting Exceeding Connections** pgpool will queue connections in case they're not being able to process immediately.
   In case of pgpool outage all such connections will be aborted, which might brake the DB/Application protocol, i.e. Application was designed to never get connection aborts.
5. **Parallel Query** A single query is executed on several nodes to reduce response time.
   In case of pgpool outage such queries will not be possible, resulting in a longer processing.

If you're fine to face such conditions and you don't treat them as a failure, then pgpool can serve you well. And if 5 minutes of outage will cost your company several thousands $, then you should seek for a more solid solution.

The higher is the cost of the outage, the more fine tuned failover system should be.
Typically, it is not just single tool used to achieve failover automation.
In each failure you will have to tweak:

- DNS, unless you want all clients' reconfiguration;
- re-initialize backups and failover procedures;
- make sure old master will not try to fight for it's role in case it comes back ([STONITH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH));
- in my experience we're people from DBA, SysAdmin, Architects and Operations departments who decide proper strategies.

Finally, in my view, pgpool is a good tool, I do use it. But it is not designed as a complete failover solution, not without extra thinking, measures taken, scripts written. Thus I've provided links to the distributed databases, they provide a much higher level of availability.

And PostgreSQL can be made distributed with a little effort due to it's great extensibility.

Comment: Does that mean, that using pgPool II really adds a single point of failure into your system? Does that really mean, that there is no way to solve the problem using pgPool?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd recommend checking out [pgBouncer](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer/) rather than pgpool. Next, what level of scaling are you attempting to reach? You might just choose to run your connection pooler on all your client systems (bouncer is light enough for this to work).

That said, vyegorov's answer is probably the direction you should really be looking at in this day and age. Are you sure you really *need* a database?

EDIT

So, the rather obvious answer is that pgPool creates a single point of failure if you only have one box running it. The obvious solution is to run multiple poolers across multiple boxes. You then need to engineer your application code to handle database disconnections. This is not as easy at it sounds, but basically you need to use 2-phase commit for non-idempotent changes. So to the greatest extent possible you should make your changes idempotent.

Based on your comments, I'd guess that maybe you have limited experience dealing with database replication? pgPool does statement based replication. There are tradeoffs here. The benefit is that it's very easy to set up. The downside is that there is no guarantee that data on the replicated databases will be identical. It is also (I believe but haven't checked lately) not compatible with 2pc.

My prior comment asking if you really *need* a database was driven by my perception that you have designed a system without going into much detail around this part of it. I have about 2 decades experience working on "this part" of similar systems. I expect you will find that there are no out of the box solutions and that the issues involved get very complicated. In other words, I'm suggesting you re-consider your design.

Comment: The question was if pgPool adds a single point of failure and how to overcome that. Also, pgBouncer is just a connection pooling software for Postgres. It should work with some replication software also. Can you suggest something for this role to cover all pgPool feaures?

Comment: This is an old thread. Still, Pgpool-HA is there to avoid pgpool becoming the single point of failure.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading this blog (with lots of information about PostgreSQL and PgPool-II):

https://www.itenlight.com/blog/2016/05/21/PostgreSQL+HA+with+pgpool-II+-+Part+5

Search for "WATCHDOG" on that same blog. With that you can configure a PgPool-II cluster. Two machines on the same subnet are required, though, and a virtual IP on the same subnet.

Hope that this is useful for anyone trying the same thing (even if this answer is a lot late).

Answer (score 0):

PGPool certainly becomes a single point of failure, but it is a much smaller one than a Postgres instance.

Though I have not attempted it yet, it should be possible to have two machines with PGPool installed, but only running on one.  You can then use Linux-HA to restart PGPool on the standby host if the primary becomes unavailable, and to optionally fail it back again when the primary comes back.  You can at the same time use Linux-HA to move a single virtual IP over as well, so that your clients can connect to a single IP for their Postgres services.

Death of the postgres server will make PGPool send queries to the backup Postgres (promoting it to master if necessary).

Death of the PGPool server will cause a brief outage (configurable, but likely in the region of <1min) until PGPool starts up on the standby, the IP address is claimed, and a gratuitous ARP sent out.  Of course, the client will have to be intelligent enough to reconnect without dying.